# How to create ajax reloading functionality in asp.net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In ASP.NET 4.*, it was easy to create an ajax reloaded table that populated the table model in the controller method by using

`@Html.Action("TableMethod")` to load the table on page load
and to reload via jQuery ajax

```
    var url = '@Url.Action("TableMethod")?params=xyz';
    $('#tableContainer').load(url);
```

How would I create a similar scenario in ASP.NET Core considering view components cannot be accessed via HTTP?
I looked at this example [Access ASP.NET 5 View Component via URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30583068/access-asp-net-5-view-component-via-url), but to have a partial view that just wraps a view component seems kind of redundant. Is this the only way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Create new action and in view add for exaple [partial view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial) (or view component) and then acces to it by AJAX by normal routing.

Comment: Yes, but the model would change based on the parameters passed in the URL.

Comment: So use `if(parameter == xyz) { view(model1) } else { view(model2) }`

Comment: Yes that would work. Or the parameters could be values to filter the table content.